# Fix y-axis bottom limit to 0 using matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation while imposing no top limit on two subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, animation, plot

I am acquiring data from an external device and I am plotting it in real-time using matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation. For this measurement, it is important to keep the bottom y-axis limit at 0, but keeping the upper limit free. The device itself returns two sets of data for this measurement so I am animating both sets at the same time, hence the subplots.

Searching online suggests using `axes.set_ylim(bottom=0)`, both in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744990/how-to-set-auto-for-upper-limit-but-keep-a-fixed-lower-limit-with-matplotlib) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53423868/matplotlib-animation-how-to-dynamically-extend-x-limits). However their solutions do not work for me.

The autoscalling that's already part of the code is using `axes.relim()` and `axes.autoscale_view(True, True, True)`, from the answer to another question which I have since forgotten. Messing with these lines of code seems to fix the viewing window but it no longer scales with the data. The data could then animate itself 'off-screen'.

I've recreated below the essence of what the acquisition (ideally) looks like since it's easier then using multiple files. 
I am assuming that the problem lies in `animate_corr(i)` with the scaling. The rest is of the code is simply getting and plotting the data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

#used to generate test data
import random
pi = np.pi 
factor = 1
random.seed(123)

#procedural data generation for left plot
def get_data(data):
    global mu
    global b
    global index
    global factor
    b=b*0.99
    factor=factor*1.01
    new_data = [factor*(((1-((1/(2*b))*np.exp(-1*(abs(i-mu))/b)))*random.random())+10) for i in index]

    return new_data

#procedural data generation for right plot
def get_data_norm(data):
    global mu
    global b
    global index

    new_data = [((1-((1/(2*b))*np.exp(-1*(abs(i-mu))/b)))+10) for i in index]
    return new_data

#animation function, assuming problem is here
def animate_corr(i):
    global dat
    global dat_norm

    dat = get_data(dat)
    dat_norm = get_data_norm(dat_norm)

    #these two not working as expected
    axs_corr[0].set_ylim((0, None), auto=True)
    axs_corr[1].set_ylim(bottom=0, top=None, auto=True)

    line_corr.set_ydata(dat)
    line_corr_norm.set_ydata(dat_norm)

    #rescales axes automatically
    axs_corr[0].relim()
    axs_corr[0].autoscale_view(True,True,True)

    axs_corr[1].relim()
    axs_corr[1].autoscale_view(True,True,True)

    return line_corr, line_corr_norm,

#plots definitions
fig_corr, axs_corr = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=True, figsize=(10,5))
fig_corr.suptitle('Animated Correlation')

#x is fixed
length = 1001
index = np.linspace(-10,10,length)

#laplacian distribution parameters
mu = 0
b = 2

#data
dat = [(1-((1/(2*b))*np.exp(-1*(abs(i-mu))/b)))+10 for i in index]
dat_norm = [(1-(1/(2*b))*np.exp(-(abs(i-mu))/b))+10 for i in index]

#initial plots
line_corr, = axs_corr[0].plot(index, dat)
line_corr_norm, = axs_corr[1].plot(index, dat_norm)

#titles
axs_corr[0].set_title('Random')
axs_corr[1].set_title('No Random')

#axes labels
fig_corr.text(0.51, 0.04, 'Time (ns)', ha='center')
fig_corr.text(0.04, 0.5, 'Coincidinces', va='center', rotation='vertical')

#animation call              
ani_corr = animation.FuncAnimation(fig_corr, animate_corr, interval=10, blit=False, save_count=50)
plt.show()
```

I would like to have both plots have the y-axis limit fixed at 0. So the left one would keep increasing its max value and seeing this reflected in its scale. The right plot would have its dip get sharper and sharper but once its smaller than 0, the plot wouldn't change its scale anymore (since this plot doesn't have its values get larger).

Comment: Are you trying to hide the fact that there are negative coincidences? In that case, filter them out before plotting.

Comment: We can't have negative coincidences, since this measurement counts the number of coincidences within a certain delay (its a histogram behind the scenes). I just couldn't get the 'test' data to behave the same way as it is with the external device, so this just an approximation. The number of coincidences increases with time, except around 0 delay, which should stay around 0 (ideally).

Comment: In that case the only problem would be that you first set the limits and then autoscale.

Comment: Why would the order matter? I based the placement on the answer of the second question I linked to.

Comment: That answer does not have any autoscaling in it, right? Anyways, autoscale_view changes the limits back. So if you call it after `set_ylim` the limits aren't set.

Comment: Ah! Ok, I see now. I have never messed with the limits like this before so wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

@ivallesp almost had it. Removing `axs_corr[0].set_ylim((0, None), auto=True)` and `axs_corr[1].set_ylim((0, None), auto=True)` from before the `set_ydata` method and placing them after the `autoscale_view`  call, for both plots, made it work as I wanted it too.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work :D.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

#used to generate test data
import random
pi = np.pi 
factor = 1
random.seed(123)

#procedural data generation for left plot
def get_data(data):
    global mu
    global b
    global index
    global factor
    b=b*0.99
    factor=factor*1.01
    new_data = [factor*(((1-((1/(2*b))*np.exp(-1*(abs(i-mu))/b)))*random.random())+10) for i in index]

    return new_data

#procedural data generation for right plot
def get_data_norm(data):
    global mu
    global b
    global index

    new_data = [((1-((1/(2*b))*np.exp(-1*(abs(i-mu))/b)))+10) for i in index]
    return new_data

#animation function, assuming problem is here
def animate_corr(i):
    global dat
    global dat_norm

    dat = get_data(dat)
    dat_norm = get_data_norm(dat_norm)

    #these two not working as expected
    axs_corr[0].set_ylim((0, None), auto=True)
    axs_corr[1].set_ylim(bottom=0, top=None, auto=True)

    line_corr.set_ydata(dat)
    line_corr_norm.set_ydata(dat_norm)

    #rescales axes automatically
    axs_corr[0].relim()
    axs_corr[0].autoscale_view(True,True,True)
    axs_corr[0].set_ylim(0, None)

    axs_corr[1].relim()
    axs_corr[1].autoscale_view(True,True,True)
    axs_corr[1].set_ylim(0, None)

    return line_corr, line_corr_norm,

#plots definitions
fig_corr, axs_corr = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=True, figsize=(10,5))
fig_corr.suptitle('Animated Correlation')

#x is fixed
length = 1001
index = np.linspace(-10,10,length)

#laplacian distribution parameters
mu = 0
b = 2

#data
dat = [(1-((1/(2*b))*np.exp(-1*(abs(i-mu))/b)))+10 for i in index]
dat_norm = [(1-(1/(2*b))*np.exp(-(abs(i-mu))/b))+10 for i in index]

#initial plots
line_corr, = axs_corr[0].plot(index, dat)
line_corr_norm, = axs_corr[1].plot(index, dat_norm)


#titles
axs_corr[0].set_title('Random')
axs_corr[1].set_title('No Random')

#axes labels
fig_corr.text(0.51, 0.04, 'Time (ns)', ha='center')
fig_corr.text(0.04, 0.5, 'Coincidinces', va='center', rotation='vertical')


#animation call              
ani_corr = animation.FuncAnimation(fig_corr, animate_corr, interval=10, blit=False, save_count=50)

plt.show()
```

Comment: It works, ish. I agree it sort-of works in the test. But the limits are at the border of the vieweing box. I think this causes it to not work in practice. Plus now there are ```set_ylim ``` lines twice (once before and once after autoscaling).

Comment: @ivallesp You're wellcome! I'll delete my comment. One hint: some users downvote when a solution doesn't show some explaining text, so a line or two of explanation couldn't hurt!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I didn't realise about it :D!